# Cordova platform add ios - Error Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: ios, cordova

I am trying to add the iOS platform to my cordova project but I keep coming across the same error. I have followed the instructions [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

When I use `cordova platform add ios` it gives me the following error

```
Shauns-MacBook-Pro:hello shaunbrown$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
Unknown option: n
Usage: head [-options] <url>...
Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.
Error: /Users/shaunbrown/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

I have tried looking around for the error but I can't find anything.

I am running xCode 5.1.1 so I know it doesn't have anything to do with that. Has anyone else came across this issue, or has a fix for this? I am pulling my hair out trying to fix it and so far I havent got anywhere.

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Do you have another version of Xcode running on your computer?

Comment: I had same problem a month ago. Just i restarted my system. The error had gone. Restart may solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. I opened my `.bash_profile` file and commented out the line that referred to my XAMPP installation.

I then restarted terminal and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might have Xcode 5.x, but your command line tools are probably set up for a previous version.

Type:

```
 xcodebuild -version
```

In a terminal.  If you need to update, read this:

[Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)